# R- Plot graph with certain variable

Tags: r, graph

This is what my dataframe looks like:

```
    Persnr    Date    AmountHolidays
1   55312     X201101 2
2   55312     X201102 4.5
3   55312     X201103 5
etc.
```

What I want to have is a graph that shows the amount of holidays (on the y-axis) of each period (Date on the x-axis) of a specific person (persnr). Basically, it's a pivot graph in R. So far I know, it is not possible to create such a graph.
Something like this is my desired result:

http://imgur.com/62VsYdJ

Is it possible in the first place to create such a model in R? If not, what is the best way for me to visualise such graph in R?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `plot(df$Persnr, df$AmountHolidays)` ?

Comment: You'd need to clean your Date variable a little bit first, but sure, it's feasible!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, if you do it like that, it won't take the Date into consideration..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could do the trick?

```
dat <- read.table(text="Persnr    Date    AmountHolidays
55312     2011-01-01 2
55312     2011-02-01 4.5
55312     2011-03-01 5
55313     2011-01-01 4
55313     2011-02-01 2.5
55313     2011-03-01 6", header=TRUE)

dat$Date <- as.POSIXct(dat$Date)
dat$Persnr <- as.factor(dat$Persnr)

# Build a primary graph
plot(AmountHolidays ~ Date, data = dat[dat$Persnr==55312,], type="l", col="red",
     xlim = c(1293858000, 1299301200), ylim=c(0,8))

# Add additional lines to it
lines(AmountHolidays ~ Date, data = dat[dat$Persnr==55313,], type="l", col="blue")

# Build and place a legend
legend(x=as.POSIXct("2011-02-19"), y=2.2, legend = levels(dat$Persnr),fill = c("red", "blue"))
```

To set X coordinates, you can either use `as.POSIXct(YYYY-MM-DD)` or `as.numeric(as.POSIXct(YYYY-MM-DD)` as I did for the xlim's.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I still lack the Persnr in the graph. Example; I want to see the amount of holidays per date of the person with the persnr 55312. Your graph does not take the Persnr into consideration.

Comment: And there's so much more you can do in terms of customization of graphs!

Comment: Thank you very much! This is quite close for what I'm looking for.

Comment: Nice solution but which could be a bit complicated and tedious if there are, for example, 50 different Persnr...

Comment: I agree ggplot2 offers more flexibility in that matter. Or maybe just using base graphics we can make this much more easily expandable. That was done quite quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with package `ggplot2`:

*First option*

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Date, y=AmountHolidays, group=Persnr)) + 
 geom_line(aes(colour=Persnr)) + scale_colour_discrete()
```

or

*Second option*

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Date, y=AmountHolidays, group=Persnr)) + 
 geom_line() + facet_grid(~Persnr)
```

One of the advantages is that you don't need to have a line per Persnr or even to specify (to know) the name or number of Persnr.

**example:**

*first option*
[image]
*second option*
[image]

***Data:***

```
dat <- structure(list(Persnr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("54000", 
"55312"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("2011-01-01", "2011-02-01", "2011-03-01"), class = "factor"), 
    AmountHolidays = c(5, 4.5, 2, 3, 6, 7)), .Names = c("Persnr", 
"Date", "AmountHolidays"), row.names = c(3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```